# current post index within content.php

Tags: custom-post-types, post-content

I have a custom post type 'projects',
I would like to add a post counter ('current project index' / 'total number projects') I would like this to show within the post content, but not sure how to implement the post index within the content.php.

I have figured out the second part to count the total amount of projects:

```
$count_projects = wp_count_posts( 'projects' );
$published_posts = $count_projects->publish;
```

But I'm not sure how to get the post index

Comment: And how are to projects ordered? From newest to oldest?

Comment: you can find get the solution of these here... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/print-current-post-index-number-within-loop

Comment: Yes Projects are ordered from newest to oldest.